# archetype.schemaextender and Grok adapters

Tags: plone, zope, grok

How it is possible to register `archetypes.schemaextenders` with `five.grok`.

The attempt:

```
class QuickNavExtender(grok.Adapter):
    """
    Define schema fiddler which injects a new field to every item.
    """

    # This field comes on every AT content item
    grok.adapts(ISchemaExtender)
    grok.provider(ISchemaExtender)
    grok.context(IBaseContent)

    #adapts(IBaseContent)
    implements(ISchemaExtender)    

    fields = [
            ExtensionBooleanField("quicknav",
                widget = atapi.BooleanWidget(
                    label="Quick jump navigation",
                    description="Allow in-page jumping by navigation links"
                ),

                # On which edit tab this field appears
                schemata = "settings"
            )
    ]
```

... is not being picked up.

But if you add this ZCML snippet and fall back Zope 3 style registration it works:

```
<adapter factory=".extender.QuickNavExtender"
   provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
class QuickNavExtender(grok.Adapter):
    grok.context(IBaseContent)
    grok.implements(ISchemaExtender)
    # fields here...
```